# How to combine two vectors with missing values?

Tags: r

I have two vectors of the same length and I'm trying to combine them such that they fill out each others missing values. For example:

```
a=c("",1,2,"")
b=c(5,"","",6)
```

I'm looking for this output:

```
5 1 2 6
```

Thanks much

Comment: Your vectors don't make sense as they can either be a numeric, or character vector, and not both.

Comment: @alex - they do work, but get coerced to character here. Not sure if OP realises that though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the normally numeric comparison via `pmax` also works:

```
as.numeric(pmax(a,b))
#[1] 5 1 2 6
```

This is because R will resort to alphanumeric sorting when `max`/`min` etc are applied to character data:

```
max(c("b","a"))
#[1] "b"
```

Answer (score 5):

And:

```
as.numeric(paste(a,b))
[1] 5 1 2 6
```

Answer (score 4):

Or:

```
a[a==""] <- b[b!=""]
as.numeric(a)
# [1] 5 1 2 6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a[a == ""] <- 0
b[b == ""] <- 0

a <- as.numeric(a)
b <- as.numeric(b)

output <- a + b
```

Answer (score 3):

```
as.numeric(ifelse(a != "", a, b))
```